# Application Transport Security and XCTestCase (Xcode Unit Testing)

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have Application Transport Security set up and working correctly for my iOS app.  I make a request to a third party web service that support TLSv1.1 and not v1.2.  Everything works great in my iOS app.  When I run my unit tests (with XCTestCase) that test the web service they fail with "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."  I tried adding my ATS exceptions to my Test Target and I still get the SSL error.  Does anyone know how to configure Xcode Unit Tests to work with ATS security exceptions?

Also, I am running this in the simulator.

Comment: Did you try resetting the simulator? Bundle resources, including the plist, are cached, so it might not have received the version with the ATS exceptions.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that.  I tried it and unfortunately I am still getting the SSL error.

Comment: Is your iOS app a target dependency of your test target?

Comment: It is the "Host Application" for my test target.  Does that make it a dependency?

Comment: No, in the build settings of your test target, the first step (Target Dependencies) should show 1 item, your app. (Note, I'm not saying this is the One True Way, just that I'm not having the problem you are, and this is how my tests are configured.)

Comment: I seem to have to opposite problem to this. I have had to enable ATS for my app because the tests require network access.

Comment: @StephenJohnson :  I am also facing same issue with Test target, my ios app running fine with Web service calls but same call from XCTest fails to create connection. Is there any work around ?

Comment: @technerd I am sorry, I can't remember what I did for this.  If I remember correctly the 3rd party service I was using updated to TLS v1.2 and then it wasn't an issue any more.